# Make screen darker Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to make the screen just a little darker for a cool slowmotion feeling.

How would I go about that with C#?

Note: I do NOT want to make the scene completely black, just a bit darker for a cool slow motion effect.

(If you have a documenation to go along with it, i'd love to see it!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply put a black square in the front of your UI and control its opacity accordingly.

Comment: You could use the post processing stack. (Download it via the package manager window) and use the color grading tool. More, you can add a vignette and more cools visual effects.